# Findall inside findall

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

it is possible make something like this?

--- ***knowledge base*** ---

```
linha( 5,[bobigny_pablo_picasso,bobigny_pantin_raymon_queneau,eglise_de_pantin,hoche,
          porte_de_pantin,ourcq,laumiere,jaures,stalingrad,gare_du_nord,gare_de_l_est,
          jacques_bonsergent,republique,oberkampf,richard_lenoir,breguet_sabin,bastille,
          quai_de_la_rapee, gare_dausterlitz,saint_marcel,campo_formio,place_ditalie],
         [10,2]).

route(71,[louis_blanc,jaures,bolivar,buttes_chaumont,botzaris,place_des_fetes,
          pre_saint_gervais],
         [10,2]).
```

--- ***knowledge base end*** ---

```
sameRoute(EI,NF):-
    findall(Y,findall(Z,member(EI,route(Y,Z,_)),NumRout),NumRouteF),
    append(NumRout,NumRouteF,NF).
```

EI is a station, and NF its supposed to return the number in the route the first parameter of the predicate route.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to achieve? It's not clear from your code as it has a lot of problems. What relation should the predicate `sameRoute/2` describe between `EI` and `NF`?

Comment: i have a lot of routes, with route have a number, like abouve, route(7,[LIST of stations],[Frequenci time]), what i what is a list, and that list need to have all number of routes, for a particular station.

Comment: This expression is a problem: `member(EI,route(Y,Z,_),NumRout)`. `member/2` expects two arguments: an element and a list. It's true if the element is a member of the list.

Comment: I had already corrected this problem, but the answer that now gives me is this:
L = [_G626]
if i try, sameRoute(jaures,L).
and its suppose to give me :
L = [5,71]

Comment: `member(EI, route(Y,Z,_))` is still not valid since `route(Y,Z,_)` isn't a list.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848142/prolog-operation-inside-findall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems you need all the routes that pass through a given station `S`.

```
findall(R, (route(R, Stations, _), member(S, Stations)), Routes).
```

The goal is a conjunction of two conditions: that `R` is the number of some route that goes through the list of stations `Stations` and that the given station `S` is a member of that list.

```
?- S = louis_blanc, findall(R, (route(R, Stations, _), member(S, Stations)), Routes).
S = louis_blanc,
Routes = [7, 71].
```